# iOS + Parse Cloud Code - updating a specific user (not logged in user)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to update a user (Which is not the current user). I figured that you have to use cloud code to make the update.

I have created the cloud function below to update the selected user. I am trying to add meetingId's to an array property which belongs to User class.

Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('updateUser', function(request, response) {

               var userId = request.params.userId,
               meetingId = request.params.meetingId;

               var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
               user = new User({ objectId: userId });

               user.addUnique("meetingsArray", meetingId)


               user.save(null, {userMasterKey:true}).then(function(user) {
                                response.success(user);
                                }, function(error) {
                                response.error(error)
                                });

               });
```

Objective-C 
//meetingId - is obtained from Meeting Object.

```
  [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"updateUser" withParameters:@{@"objectId":user.objectId, @"meetingsArray":meetingId} block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"%@",result);
         }else if(error){
             NSLog(@"%@", error);
         }
     }];
```

When I run the app - I get the following error code:

```
Error Domain=Parse Code=141 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 141.)" UserInfo=0x1704f2780 {code=141, temporary=0, error={"code":201,"message":"missing user password"}, originalError=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)"}
```

I'm new to Cloud code - i just basically want to update the array that belongs to the selected user and add a meetingId to it. Any help would be greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code that will prevent it from working:

1. the cloud code expects the meeting id parameter to be named `@"meetingId"`, so change the parameters passed to `@{@"objectId":user.objectId, @"meetingId":meetingId}`
2. use `Parse.User`, not `'_User'` to extend user.
3. get - don't build - the user being updated

Summing up...

```
Parse.Cloud.define('updateUser', function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId;
    var meetingId = request.params.meetingId;

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.get(userId).then(function(user) {
        user.addUnique("meetingsArray", meetingId);
        return user.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});
    }).then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! thank you for clarifying how to use cloud function. You code should work - I'm getting the following error.   "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 141.)" UserInfo=0x1702f8080 {code=141, temporary=0, error={"code":101,"message":"Object not found."},    --- not sure why this is happening because the user i'm trying to update does exist and has a property (array) to store the meetingid's.

Comment: So you've examined the userid passed to the cloud and confirmed that there's a user with that id in the data browser?

Comment: correct -im checking that the user i want to update exists before it get passed in to [ PFCloud callFunctionInBackground....];

Comment: Okay, but please do the check manually.  Log the id, and log the meetingId.  Then find them in the data browser.  (If you do the check in code, there's a chance that there's a mistake in the code).

Comment: you have typo in your code: Should be `useMasterKey` instead of `userMasterKey`

Answer (score 1):

I was still getting the error after implementing @danh's answer. I needed to add

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()
```

in the .js file then everything worked perfect!

Comment: I had the same, but there is a typo in @danh's answer. Should be     `useMasterKey` instead of `userMasterKey`

Comment: Sorry about this.  Fixed my answer.